# Keras resizing images inside Model - ValueError Not a symbolic tensor

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am starting to work my way into Keras.

Previously I coded my own generator and Network, but here is the problem I preprocessed my data before passing it to the neural network. Now the task is to do this inside keras.

My earlier Model looked like this:

```
input_shape = (64, 64, 3)
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x / 255 - 0.5, input_shape=input_shape))
        model.add(Convolution2D(24, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', subsample=(2, 2), W_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Convolution2D(36, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', subsample=(2, 2), W_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Convolution2D(48, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', subsample=(2, 2), W_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', subsample=(2, 2), W_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='valid', subsample=(2, 2), W_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(80, W_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(40, W_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(16, W_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(10, W_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
        model.add(Dense(1, W_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
        adam = Adam(lr=0.0001)
        model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse')
        model.summary()
    return model
```

This together with my resizing of the images before passing them into the Network to train it worked perfectly well. So to make it possible for my network to take the images from the game, the resizing needs to happen inside the network. But already with creating an InputLayer from which I could resize the images I get a **ValueError** 
I did not change much inside the network but it now looks like this:

```
img_shape = (160, 320, 3)
    inputLayer = InputLayer(input_shape=(None, 160, 320, 3))
    normalize = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255 - 0.5, input_shape=img_shape)(inputLayer)
    cropped = Cropping2D(cropping=((50, 20), (0, 0)), input_shape=(160, 320, 3))(normalize)
    conv1 = Convolution2D(24, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', subsample=(2, 2), W_regularizer=l2(0.001))(cropped)
    conv1_activ = Activation("relu")(conv1)
    conv2 = Convolution2D(36, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', subsample=(2, 2), W_regularizer=l2(0.001))(conv1_activ)
    conv2_activ = Activation("relu")(conv2)
    conv3 = Convolution2D(48, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', subsample=(2, 2), W_regularizer=l2(0.001))(conv2_activ)
    conv3_activ = Activation("relu")(conv3)
    conv4 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', subsample=(2, 2), W_regularizer=l2(0.001))(conv3_activ)
    conv4_activ = Activation("relu")(conv4)
    conv5 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='valid', subsample=(2, 2), W_regularizer=l2(0.001))(conv4_activ)
    conv5_activ = Activation("relu")(conv5)
    flattened = Flatten()(conv5_activ)
    fullyConnected1 = Dense(80, W_regularizer=l2(0.001))(flattened)
    dropOut1 = Dropout(0.5)(fullyConnected1)
    fullyConnected2 = Dense(40, W_regularizer=l2(0.001))(dropOut1)
    dropOut2 = Dropout(0.5)(fullyConnected2)
    fullyConnected3 = Dense(16, W_regularizer=l2(0.001))(dropOut2)
    dropOut3 = Dropout(0.5)(fullyConnected3)
    fullyConnected4 = Dense(10, W_regularizer=l2(0.001))(dropOut3)
    fullyConnected5 = Dense(1, W_regularizer=l2(0.001))(fullyConnected4)
    opt = Adam(lr=0.0001)
    model = Model(inputs=normalize, outputs=fullyConnected5)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="mse")
    model.summary()
    return model
```

The error when calling the function is the following

```
    ValueError: Layer lambda_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.
 Received type: <class 'keras.engine.topology.InputLayer'>. Full input: [<keras.engine.topology.InputLayer object at 0x1213a6fd0>]. 
All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

I already have an idea resizing the images with the original tensorflow

```
Lambda(lambda image: ktf.image.resize_images(image, (64, 64)))(inputLayer)
```

So the only real problem would be how to actually get this work with this ValueError, I don't know what to do here. Thank you guys

Comment: Start from deleting `None` from `input_shape` in your `InputLayer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Input(img_shape)` instead of `InputLayer(input_shape=(None, 160, 320, 3))`.

You cannot pass a "layer" to another layer, you must pass a "tensor".

The logic of each line when defining the model is:

```
outputTensor = SomeLayer(blablabla)(inputTensor)
```

`InputLayer` itself is not a tensor, but `Input` is.

---

Hints:

- you don't need to pass `input_shape` to those layers. Once the `Input(shape)` is defined, everything else does automatic inferring.
- if you're using theano backend, you will probably need `output_shape=...` in your lambda layers.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems like this did not work aswell, the error just hanged  
  File "/Users/patrickhentschel/Documents/CarND-Behavioral-Cloning-P3-master/model.py", line 247, in main
    model = testModel()
  File "/Users/patrickhentschel/Documents/CarND-Behavioral-Cloning-P3-master/model.py", line 223, in testModel
    model.add(Input(shapeInput))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 420, in add
    'Found: ' + str(layer))
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 64, 64, 3), dtype=float32)

Comment: You changed to a `Sequential` model? You were using a functional `Model` before. My answer was based on `Model`. --- So, you must add **layers to a sequential model** (but never an input layers, just an `input_shape` to the first layer). Or you should build a regular `Model` by **calling layers passing them tensors**.

Comment: In a sequential model, you don't add inputs, you just add the first layer, exactly as in the first code in your question.

Comment: yes I changed back to a Sequential model, sorry for being that dumb, but it seems like I my brain does not want to understand that part... My first Layer is the Lambda Layer
`model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x / 255 - 0.5, input_shape=Input(input_shape))` ?

Comment: `model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x / 255 - 0.5, input_shape=input_shape)) ` -- If using `theano`, you will probably need to add the `output_shape=input_shape` too.